# Ajax loading spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add loading spinner (some gif) for each image while loading and when image is loaded I want to remove spinner.
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?',
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    tags    : 'cats',
    format  : "json"
  }
}).done(function( responseData ){
  html = '<row>';
  $.each( responseData.items, function( index, cat ){
    html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
    html += '<a href="' + cat.link +'" class="thumbnail">';
    html += '<img src="' + cat.media.m + '" alt="" class="images">';
    tml += '</a></div>';
  }); // end $.each
  html += '</row>';
  $('#photos').html(html);
  $searchField.attr('disabled', false);
  $submitButton.attr('disabled', false).text('Search');
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somthing like this:

```
...
html += '<img src="' + cat.media.m + '" alt="" class="images hidden">';
html += '<span class="spinner"></span>';
...


$("#photos img").load(function() {
    $(this).show();
    $(this).siblings('.spinner').remove();
});
```

The `hidden` class in the img tag hides your image using css:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

It's up to you how you'll add the spinner in the `<span class="spinner"></span>`

Comment: Great solution, i modified it and add .then()  method after .done(). Here is code that I added after .done() method 
`.then(function(){
   $('.images').load(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).siblings('.spinner').remove();
   });
});`

Comment: Great. `$(this).removeClass('hidden');` in this case is better than `$(this).show();`

Answer (score 0):

use **beforeSend** and **complete** option at Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?      jsoncallback=?',
   cache: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
      tags    : 'cats',
      format  : "json"
   },
   beforeSend: {
      // add loading spinner
   },
   complete: {
      // remove loading spinner
   }
   }).done(function( responseData ){
      html = '<row>';
      $.each( responseData.items, function( index, cat ){
         html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
         html += '<a href="' + cat.link +'" class="thumbnail">';
         html += '<img src="' + cat.media.m + '" alt="" class="images">';
         tml += '</a></div>';
      }); // end $.each
      html += '</row>';
      $('#photos').html(html);
      $searchField.attr('disabled', false);
      $submitButton.attr('disabled', false).text('Search');
   });
```